# Can't parse entities: unexpected end tag at byte offset 0

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

i dont known, pls help

```
async def getcatalog(message: types.message):
    if catalog.find_one({"type": 0}) is None:
        await message.answer('К сожалению, товаров нет в наличии')
    else:
        inline_kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for cat in catalog.find({"type": 0}):
            inline_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(cat['name'], callback_data=cat['name'])
            inline_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(inline_btn)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'</b> Выберите нужный вам товар:</b>', reply_markup=inline_kb)
```

Can't parse entities: unexpected end tag at byte offset 0
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```py
 f'</b> Выберите нужный вам товар:</b>'
```

with:

```
 f'<b> Выберите нужный вам товар:</b>'
```